# Right way to solve this reccurence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am not that good in mathematics , I have solved many simple relations. But I am not be able to solve the following. This is not a homework. I found it during analysis of a program.

$T(n)=2T(n-1)+\log(2T(n-1))$

Comment: What is $t$?  Is it a constant?

Comment: sorry that is 'n'  not 't'. edited!

Answer (score 0):

An exact solution is very unlikely. However, if you disregard the $\log$ term, you see that $T(n) \approx 2^n \cdot T_0$. If you substitute this into the logarithmic term, you get something of the sort:

$$
T(n) = 2 T(n - 1) + n + 1 + \log T_0
$$

You can solve this to get a better approximation, and perhaps get asymptotics or bounds on $T(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$T_n
\approx 2^nT_0$,
let
$T_n = 2^nT_0u_n
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
T(n) 
&= 2T(n-1)+\log(2T(n-1))\\
\text{so}\\
2^nT_0u_n 
&= 2\cdot 2^{n-1}T_0u_{n-1}+\log(2\cdot 2^{n-1}T_0u_{n-1})\\
\text{or}\\
u_n
&= u_{n-1}+\dfrac{n\log(2)+\log(T_0)}{2^nT_0}+\dfrac{\log(u_n)}{2^nT_0}\\
\end{array}
$

From this you can show that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n$
exists,
so
$T_N \approx c2^n$
where
$c =
\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n
$.